# RTFPipe causes issues in font declaration

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox, rtf

I'd like to use the 3rd party library [RTFPipe](https://github.com/erdomke/RtfPipe) to convert Richtextbox text to html.

Problem:

1. when i declare this library, `Private FontStyleTitre As Font` declarations (not related) becomes in error.

Each line got two erros:

[BC30311](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/misc/bc30311?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(BC30311)): Value of type FontFamily cannot be converted to Integer

[BC30057](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/misc/bc30057?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(BC30057)): Too many arguments to 'Public Overloads Sub New(id As Integer)'

2. `e.Graphics.DrawString` is in error too.

[BC30518](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/misc/bc30518?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(BC30518)): Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'DrawString' can be called with these arguments: Public Overloads Sub DrawString(s As String, font As Font, brush As Brush, point As PointF)

```
Imports MySql.Data.Types
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Imports System.Text
Imports System.IO
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports iTextSharp.text.pdf
Imports RtfPipe

Public Class frmCorpusManagement
    Private WithEvents frmCorpusAddObjectNew As frmCorpusAddObject
    Private frmWaitingCorpus As New frmTechWaiting
    Private objectToAdd As FormatedObjectForCorpus
    Private blnLoadInProgress As Boolean
    Private intcmbFontStyleTotalHeight As Integer = 0
    Private FontStyleTitre1 As Font = New Font(New FontFamily("Lato"), 18, FontStyle.Bold, 3)
    Private FontStyleTitre2 As Font = New Font(New FontFamily("Lato"), 16, FontStyle.Underline Or FontStyle.Bold, 3)
    Private FontStyleTitre3 As Font = New Font(New FontFamily("Lato"), 14, FontStyle.Underline Or FontStyle.Bold, 3)
    Private FontStyleTitre4 As Font = New Font(New FontFamily("Lato"), 12, FontStyle.Underline, 3)
    Private FontStyleCorpsdeTexte As Font = New Font(New FontFamily("Lato"), 12, FontStyle.Regular, 3)
    Private FontStyleForDisplay As Font = New Font(New FontFamily("Lato"), 9, FontStyle.Regular, 3)
[...]
Private Sub cmbFontStyle_DrawItem(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DrawItemEventArgs)
        e.DrawBackground()
        Dim myItem As CorpusFontStyleItem = DirectCast(cmbFontStyle.Items(e.Index), CorpusFontStyleItem)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(myItem.strTextStyleName, myItem.fontTextStyle, New SolidBrush(Color.Black), e.Bounds)
        e.DrawFocusRectangle()
    End Sub
[...]
End Class
```

Comment: Ok. First clue: RTFPipe use a class named Font.
`Namespace RtfPipe

    Public Class Font
        Implements IToken

        Public Sub New(id As Integer)

        Public ReadOnly Property Id As Integer
        Public ReadOnly Property Name As String
        Public ReadOnly Property Encoding As Encoding
        Public ReadOnly Property Type As TokenType
        Public ReadOnly Property Category As FontFamilyCategory
    End Class
End Namespace
`

Comment: One solution is to use RTFPipe in another part of the code. It's some of "degraded" solution...

Comment: Fully qualify `Font` as to which `Font` class you are referring to. `System.Drawing.Font`

Comment: @Mary i've thought about this solution but how to fully qualify FontFamily?